# Ionic 3 lazy loading make lag with large html file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

i am using ionic 3 in my project and i have some problems with lazy load.

I have a `ResultPage` with the template `resultpage.html` has more than **1000** html lines code. In the `HomePage` i want to navigate to `ResultPage` by `navCtrl.setRoot`. When i call it, the screen freeze in 3-4s before take me to the `ResultPage`. It is really a bad UX. It only happen with lagre teamplate and in the first time i enter that page. I decide to remove lazy load in `ResultPage` and the lag disapear. I don't know is it a right way? Can some one please tell me what should i do in this case?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 7):

One way to hide that from the user, would be to still use lazy load in your app, but **preloading eagerly** that specific page. You can take a look at [the docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/IonicPage/#priority) for more info.

> By default, preloading is turned off so setting this property would do
>   nothing. Preloading eagerly loads all deep links after the application
>   boots instead of on demand as needed. To enable preloading, set
>   preloadModules in the main application module config to true:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      preloadModules: true // <- Here!
    })
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> If preloading is turned on, it will load the modules based on the
>   value of priority. The following values are possible for priority:
>   "high", "low", and "off". When there is no priority, it will be set to
>   "low".
>
> All deep links with their priority set to "high" will be loaded first.
>   Upon completion of loading the "high" priority modules, all deep links
>   with a priority of "low" (or no priority) will be loaded
>
> Setting the priority is as simple as passing it to the @IonicPage
>   decorator:

```
@IonicPage({
  name: 'my-page',
  priority: 'high'
})
```

So in your case, I'd try by setting the priority to high to:

- The first pages that the user will interact with when the app is loaded (the HomePage for example)
- The `ResultPage` in order to keep it already preloaded and show it faster when the user is redirected to it.

**Please notice that preloading pages eagerly may increase the startup time of your app, so try to preload pages as little as possible.**

Comment: Thank for your reply. I will try your solution and take a feedback. But i have an addition question that can i set default `priority` to off? Because i have more than 50 pages so i dont want to set `priority:off` by hand.

Comment: Hmm but according to the docs _Upon completion of loading the "high" priority modules, all deep links with a priority of "low" (or no priority) will be loaded_ so setting the priority to _off_ or leaving it by default (low) would be pretty much the same in this case (since you just use the priority to preload some pages, but you don't care how the rest of the pages are loaded)... Now that you mention that you have 50+ pages, I'm afraid that preloading the pages may affect the loading time of the app making it kind of slow... Please let me know what happens if you test this approach :)

Comment: Here is the result:Test case1: all page `priority:low`, 2 page `priority: high`: 9s white screen (much faster than no preload) but many seconds screen freeze, only show html, cannot do anything.

Comment: Test case2: all page `priority:off`, 2 page `priority:high`: 9s white screen, 5s freeze screen. Test case3: all page `priority:off`, 1 page `priority:low`: 9s white screen, 4s freeze screen

Comment: So i think the app load faster but it need time to load preload page so i can not interact with screen in this time. What should i do now?

Comment: Hmm.. about that html file with 1000 lines, is there a way to reduce the amount of lines? Or maybe load some of them after the page has been loaded? May I ask, why does that page have some many lines of code? I just ask in order to know if we can optimice that part of the code and reduce the freeze time when loading the app

Comment: It is a aggregate page. I have a segment list in it. Each segment have so many html. Despite of using ngIf, it seem like ngIf have no effect to loading time

Comment: And splitting each segment into a different page (that can be pushed from the `ResultsPage` is not a valid option? Because even if you include some `NgIf`, angular still needs to parse all the html code, and that's what is taking so much time

Comment: Yeah, i thought i would do like that. But it will take some efforts because of logic code. Now i decide keeping `ResultPage` no more lazy load. Thank you for your time. I can not accept your answer but i up voted it.

Comment: Thanks, and apologies for not being able to help :(

Comment: Great effort.First time I saw this feature.+1 :) @sebaferreras

Comment: Thanks! It still being improved, but it's a great feature and can improve the _perceived performance_ a lot :)